# Uploading file from Node.JS SDK to GraphQL using graphql-upload

Tags: node.js, file-upload, graphql, nestjs, apollo

I'm looking to upload a file to a graphql endpoint that streams the file to an output.
On the graphql server it looks like the basic example of apollo.

```
async uploadFile(
    @Args({ name: 'file', type: () => GraphQLUpload }) file,
    @CurrentUser() user,
  ): Promise<string> {
    const { createReadStream, filename } = await file;

    // for uploading temporary nfts
    const randomFileName = generateRandomFileName(filename);

    const readStream = createReadStream();
    const out = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, randomFileName));
    readStream.pipe(out);

    await finished(out);
}
```

using the `graphqlUploadExpress` middleware

```
graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 100, maxFiles: 1 })
```

When using React.JS to upload, it all works fine. However, when using a Node.JS client, it fails to upload. The image results in double the size, the mimetype is not set and the image is not viewable.

I have tried different methods, but i think it's something to do with the read stream that's passed.

```
    const fileStream = await fs.createReadStream(
        path.join(__dirname, "image.png"),
        {
          encoding: "utf8",
        }
      );
    
      const response = await request(
        GRAPHQL_URL,
        UPLOAD,
        {
          file: fileStream,
        },
        {
          "X-API-KEY": apiKey,
        }
      );
```

Also tried using `form-data`

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(
    "operations",
    JSON.stringify({ query: print(UPLOAD), variables: { file: null } })
  );
  formData.append(
    "map",
    JSON.stringify({
      "0": ["variables.file"],
    })
  );

  const file = await streamToString(fileStream);

  formData.append("0", file, "image.png");

  console.log(formData.getHeaders());

  return axios.post(GRAPHQL_URL, formData, {
    headers: {
      ...formData.getHeaders(),
    },
});
```

Any ideas? On the client it uses the `File` object, not sure how to simulate that on a Node.JS client

Comment: Huh I give up using a gql for file upload, and had totally different problem, so at the end I just end up with simple http multipart request.

Comment: Turns out i just had to remove the `utf8` encoding as it's an image which is binary :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i just had to remove the `utf8` encoding. the following sample works

```
const fileStream = await fs.createReadStream(
    path.join(__dirname, "image.png")
  );

  const response = await request(
    GRAPHQL_URL,
    UPLOAD,
    {
      file: fileStream,
    },
    {
      "X-API-KEY": apiKey,
    }
  );
```